# Maximal 2-packing in edge-graph

Tags: graph-theory

We have some arbitrary graph $G$ and try to find maximal "special" matching $M$ in it. Here "special" means that for every pair of edges $e$ and $f$ in $M$, $d(e,f) \geq 2$.

It was spotted that this is exactly 2-packing in edge-graph, but I can't find the definition of 2-packing in edge-graph. Does this equivalence holds and if so, has 2-packing in edge-graph problem already been solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the On the number of $2$-packings in a connected graph Junosza-Szaniawski and Rzazewski defined $2$-packing of a graph $G$ as a subset of its vertex set, in which all the vertices are in distance at least $3$ from each other. Therefore if we look at the edge graph of our original graph $G$, these two problems (finding maximal "special" matching in $G$ and finding maximal $2$-packing in edge graph of $G$) are equivalent.